# Ler mais de um arquivo .xls em python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, xls

Postei uma pergunta bem parecida com essa há alguns dias, porém dessa vez, estou tentando fazer algo bem mais genérico.
Quero pegar a informação da linha 0 e 1. O Código abaixo está completo, e está gerando a saída do arquivo entrada.xls corretamente.

```
import xlrd
import xlwt

# Open the input worksheet 
inputWorkbook = xlrd.open_workbook('entrada.xls', formatting_info=True)

# select the correct sheet for input
inputSheet = inputWorkbook.sheet_by_name('idade')

# Create the output worksheet
outputWorkbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")

# Add a new sheet to the output worksheet
outputSheet = outputWorkbook.add_sheet('idade')

# Output sheet header's style
headerStyle = xlwt.easyxf('font: height 200, bold 1, color white;''pattern: pattern solid, fore_color black; ')

for coluna in range(inputSheet.ncols):
    outputSheet.write(0, coluna, inputSheet.cell_value(1, coluna), headerStyle);
    outputSheet.write(1, coluna, inputSheet.cell_value(2, coluna));

outputWorkbook.save("resultado.xls")
```

O problema: Ler mais de 10 arquivos .xls de uma vez.
Não quero a informação Só do entrada.xls, mas também de, entrada1.xls, entrada2.xls, entrada3.xls ...

Comment: É muito difícil responder a essa sua pergunta assim no abstrato, pois não sei exatamente o que você está querendo fazer com esses arquivos, se precisa combinar seus resultados ou não, etc. Tentei responder da melhor forma que pude, mas se isso não esclarecer sua dúvida, favor [edit] sua pergunta colocando o máximo de **contexto** possível (i.e. diga o que quer fazer, como está tentando fazer, algum trecho relevante de código, etc).

Comment: Oi, eu editei a pergunta para melhorar o que quero fazer.

Comment: Melhorou bastante, mas ainda deixou algumas dúvidas: 1) todos os arquivos `entradaN.xls` têm estrutura igual? i.e. uma página chamada `idade`, de onde você pretende extrair as linhas `1` e `2` de todas as colunas (tal como você está fazendo nesse exemplo); ou não? 2) Onde serão colocadas as informações das demais entradas? A primeira foi pras linhas `0` e `1` da saída, a próxima irá pras linhas `2` e `3`? Ou é tudo nas duas primeiras linhas, e a próxima irá simplesmente acrescentar mais colunas? Ou ainda: só a primeira terá cabeçalhos, as seguintes não... Etc.

Comment: Que bom. 1) Sim, todos os arquivos entradaN.xls tem a mesma estrutura. Por exemplo, tem 10 colunas e 2 linhas. 2) Isso mesmo, preciso tirar as informaçãos de todas as colunas e linhas 0 e 1 do arquivo de entrada, e para linha retirada será adicionado na linha 0 e 1, e depois 2 e 3 e assim por diante. Estou estudando sobre como criar função igual você ensinou abaixo, mas ainda estou com dificuldades. Mas estou atenta aos seus ensinamentos. Obrigada

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com um exemplo completo. No caso, o `zip` foi desnecessário, mas a estrutura geral da solução permaneceu a mesma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu sugiro que você dê uma olhada na função [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) e - caso ainda não domine esse conceito - nas [compreensões de lista](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compreens%C3%A3o_de_lista) (*list comprehensions*). Isso vai te ajudar bastante a estruturar seu código.

Se você possui um código pronto que trata de um único arquivo:

```
workbook_r = open_workbook('arquivo.xls', formatting_info=True)
worksheet_r = workbook_r.sheet_by_index(0)
...
```

O caminho "natural" para se passar pra mais um arquivo é o uso de funções:

```
def ler_arquivo(nome):
    workbook_r = open_workbook(nome, formatting_info=True)
    worksheet_r = workbook_r.sheet_by_index(0)
    ...
    return resultados # Aquilo que você quer extrair do arquivo

ler_arquivo('arquivo.xls')
```

Se você tem N arquivos, então, você vai chamar essa função N vezes, extraindo os resultados individuais de cada um (se os arquivos tiverem estruturas diferentes então você terá que fazer funções diferentes para cada "tipo" de arquivo, é claro):

```
arquivos = ['arquivo1.xls', 'arquivo2.xls', 'arquivo3.xls']
resultados = [ler_arquivo(nome) for nome in arquivos]
```

Ok, até aqui provavelmente eu não disse nada que você já não soubesse. O problema agora é - como **combinar** os resultados do processamento de cada arquivo? É aí que entra a função `zip`. Digamos que parte dos seus resultados são valores de uma coluna do arquivo:

```
def ler_arquivo(nome):
    ...
    coluna_que_me_interessa = []
    ... # Extrai os valores de uma coluna que te interesse e coloque na lista
    return {
        "minha_coluna":coluna_que_me_interessa,
        ... # outros dados
    }
```

Por exemplo, digamos que o arquivo Excel A contenha "pesos" e o arquivo B contenha "medidas de altura" - e você quer usar ambos pra fazer um cálculo.

```
resultados1 = ler_arquivo('pessoas_pesos.xls')
resultados2 = ler_arquivo('pessoas_alturas.xls')

pesos = resultados1['minha_coluna']
alturas = resultados2['minha_coluna']

for i in range(len(pesos)):
    imc = pesos[i] / alturas[i]*alturas[i]
```

Em vez de fazer esse loop "estranho", você pode usar a função `zip` para combinar os elementos das listas `pesos` e `alturas` dois a dois:

```
pesos = [50,70,60]
alturas = [160,180,165]

zip(pesos, alturas) # [(50,160), (70,180), (60,165)]
```

De modo que você possa usar o par em uma compreensão de lista:

```
def calcular_imc(peso, altura): # Exemplo; na prática, suas funções serão mais complexas
    ...

imcs = [calcular_imc(x,y) for (x,y) in zip(pesos, alturas)]
```

Por fim, respondendo à sua pergunta: e se eu tiver um número **arbitrário** de arquivos? Nesse caso (e assumindo que os arquivos são homogêneos, i.e. com a mesma estrutura) você pode passar uma lista de argumentos pro `zip` de forma dinâmica. Exemplo:

```
arquivos = ['arquivo1.xls', 'arquivo2.xls', 'arquivo3.xls']
resultados = [ler_arquivo(nome) for nome in arquivos]

minha_coluna = [r['minha_coluna'] for r in resultados]
calculo = [meu_calculo(x) for x in zip(*minha_coluna)]
```

Isso vai fazer com que `meu_calculo` receba uma lista contendo os valores de cada coluna [de cada arquivo] correspondentes à linha 1, depois uma lista pra linha 2, etc.

---

**Atualização:** adaptando então a técnica descrita para o seu caso específico (no caso, o `zip` foi desnecessário):

```
def ler_arquivo(nome):
    inputWorkbook = xlrd.open_workbook(nome, formatting_info=True)
    inputSheet = inputWorkbook.sheet_by_name('idade')
    return {
        "ncols":inputSheet.ncols,
         # As duas linhas que interessam
        "linha1":[inputSheet.cell_value(1, coluna) for coluna in range(inputSheet.ncols)],
        "linha2":[inputSheet.cell_value(2, coluna) for coluna in range(inputSheet.ncols)],
    }

arquivos = ["entrada{}.xls".format(i+1) for i in range(10)]
resultados = [ler_arquivo(nome) for nome in arquivos]

outputWorkbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
outputSheet = outputWorkbook.add_sheet('idade')
headerStyle = xlwt.easyxf('font: height 200, bold 1, color white;''pattern: pattern solid, fore_color black; ')

# Percorre os resultados de cada arquivo, incrementando a linha em 2
linha = 0
for resultado in resultados:
    for coluna in range(resultado["ncols"]):
        outputSheet.write(linha+0, coluna, resultado["linha1"][coluna], headerStyle)
        outputSheet.write(linha+1, coluna, resultado["linha2"][coluna])
    linha = linha + 2

outputWorkbook.save("resultado.xls")
```

Comment: Deu certo! Só alterei a posição da linha outputWorkbook e outputSheet, para antes da função, pois são essas linhas que "abrem" o(s) arquivo(s) a serem lidos. Agora vou ler e entender o seu raciocínio, se eu tiver alguma dúvida na sua lógica eu te pergunto novamente. Obrigada!

Answer (score -1):

ola, gostaria de fazer algo parecido com isso. mas ao inves de ele pegar informações de duas linhas, eu quero que ele pegue duas colunas inteiras do arquivo de entrada e escreva no arquivo de saida. podriam me ajudar?

Comment: Tiago, bom vindo ao stackoverflow em português, faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e veja como criar uma pergunta, não faça isso em perguntas já existentes.