# Obtenção de dados do excel e transformando em lista, pelo Python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, lista

```
import xlrd 

def ler_arquivo(teste_termal1):
    tt1= xlrd.open_workbook('teste_termal1.xls', formatting_info=True)
    eajp60= workbook_r.sheet_by_index(3)
    Coluna_4=[3]
    Coluna_13=[12]
    return {
    "Ct":Coluna_4,
    "Sa":Coluna_13,
    }
    CT=[Ct]
    SA=[Sa]
for i in range(len(SA)):
    satxct=CT*SA
print CT, SA , satxct
```

escrevi com ajuda de vocês esse pequeno script, nele tento buscar os valores de uma coluna em uma pagina no excel, sendo assim achei a logica boa, porem ele diz que o "Ct" não está definido, então como faço para definir esse "Ct"?

Comment: Em que linha ocorre o erro? Seu código está um pouco confuso: eu não entendi a parte `CT=[Ct]` **após** o retorno da função. Pergunta 1: isso não deveria estar fora da função, ou seja, não indentado juntamente com o restante do código (o `for` e o `print`)? Pergunta 2: o que você desejou fazer ao usar `CT=[Ct]`? Afinal, a sua função parece retornar um *dictionary*, então esse valor precisaria ser armazenado em uma variável para que campo "Ct" fosse acessado via indexação por string (por exemplo, assim: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3765543/2896619)

Comment: Outra coisa confusa é esse tipo de instrução: `Coluna_13=[12]`. Não entendi a intenção, mas o que isso faz é criar uma lista/vetor com um único elemento `12`: abra o console e execute: `>>> Coluna_13=[12]`; então execute: `>>> Coluna_13`; vai retornar: `[12]`. Será que a sua intenção não era fazer, nesse caso: `Coluna_13=eajp60[12]`?

Comment: A instrução Coluna_13 é só para saber que estou me referindo a coluna 13 do Excel, e para resgatar ela como "[12]" já que se trata de uma coluna inteira. O "CT" ao meu ver deveria ser uma lista que contem ds dados da Coluna_4, e SA da coluna_13. Eu estou querendo retorna os valores da coluna em uma lista.

Comment: Segue de onde eu tentei tirar esse codigo [Link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33830/ler-mais-de-um-arquivo-xls-em-python)

Answer (score 3):

Há vários erros nesse código. A versão corrigida ficaria assim:

```
import xlrd 

def ler_arquivo():
    tt1 = xlrd.open_workbook('teste_termal1.xls', formatting_info=True)
    eajp60 = workbook_r.sheet_by_index(3)
    dicionario = {}
    dicionario["Ct"] = eajp60[3]
    dicionario["Sa"] = eajp60[12]
    return dicionario

dicionario_retorno = ler_arquivo()
satxct = dicionario["Ct"] * dicionario["Sa"]

print(dicionario["Ct"], dicionario["Sa"], satxct)
```

Vou discutir parte a parte das alterações. Na declaração da função:

```
def ler_arquivo(teste_termal1):
```

Você não usa a varíavel `teste_termal1`, então retirei ela.

Aqui:

```
Coluna_4=[3]
Coluna_13=[12]
```

Variáveis em Python normalmente não seguem esta convenção de iniciar por maiúsculas. Como elas não possuem utilidade, também as retirei e troquei por um dicionário, que presumo que era o objetivo inicial.

Isto aqui:

```
Coluna_4=[3]
```

Define uma variável `Coluna_4` como sendo uma lista com um único elemento. No caso, `3`. Da mesma forma, isto:

```
Coluna_13=[12]
```

Também define uma outra variável chamada `Coluna_13` como sendo uma outra lista com um único valor. No caso, `12`.

Isto:

```
return {
    "Ct":Coluna_4,
    "Sa":Coluna_13,
}
```

Você retorna um dicionário com dois índices, `"Ct"` e `"Sa"`, cujos valores são de uma lista de um elemento cada. No caso:

```
{
    "Ct": [3],
    "Sa": [12]
}
```

Isto aqui não faz o menor sentido:

```
CT=[Ct]
SA=[Sa]
```

O erro acontece porque `Ct` obviamente não está definido em nenhuma parte do código. O erro aconteceria na linha de baixo pelo mesmo motivo. `Sa` também é uma variável que não está definida.